# Expression blend 4 Silverlight version Incompatibility

Tags: silverlight, version, expression-blend, incompatibility

I am getting the below error when I try create new sketch flow application

"Blend cannot continue because of compatible silverlight version could not be found"

I have the following installed

1. Microsoft Silverlight version 4.0.50524.0
2. Microsoft Silverlight 4 SDK
3. Microsoft Silverlight 4 Toolkit April 2010
4. Microsoft Silverlight 4 Tools for Visual Studio 2010
5. Microsoft Silverlight 3 SDK
6. Microsoft Silverlight 3 Tools for Visual Studio 2008 SP1 -ENU
7. Microsoft Silverlight 3 toolkit November 2009

Please suggest me a fix

Comment: Which version of Blend have you got installed?

Comment: Expression Blend 4.0 trial version

Answer (score 0):

Is Blend the current trial or the RC?  Is Visual Studio 2010 GA or RC or Beta?  That is the same version of Silverlight I have - what are the versions of Blend, the SDK, and the Toolkit?

Comment: The problem was with system.dll. I uninstalled the newer version from GAC and it worked. Thanks a lot